# How can I refresh my Spotify access token using Python?

Tags: python, web

```py
import base64
from requests import post, get
import json

def refreshToken(access_token):
    data = {"grant_type":"refresh_token",
            "refresh_token": access_token,
            }
    url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
    headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
               }
    result = post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    json_result = json.loads(result.content)
    refreshed_token = json_result['refresh_token']
    
    return refreshed_token
```

I tried this code but did not work. How can I fix this?

I got this error:

> refreshed_token = json_result['refresh_token']
> KeyError: 'refresh_token'

response is 400

Comment: Hi, have you checked this https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/tutorials/refreshing-tokens ?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75710572/python-script-token-refresh-mechanism-problem-for-spotify-api/75711352#75711352) gets access token by refresh token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import json
import requests  # Import the requests module for making HTTP requests

def refreshToken(access_token):
    data = {
        "grant_type": "refresh_token",
        "refresh_token": access_token,
    }
    url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token"
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    }
    
    # Use the 'requests.post' function instead of 'post'
    result = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    
    # Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
    if result.status_code == 200:
        json_result = result.json()
        refreshed_token = json_result.get('refresh_token')  # Use 'get' to avoid KeyError if 'refresh_token' is not present
        return refreshed_token
    else:
        # Handle the case when the request was not successful
        print(f"Error: {result.status_code}")
        return None
```

Comment: I imported libraries that you mentioned but didnot work.displaying error 400

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).